# AndroidJUnit4 Espresso crash because of same id used in other fragments

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

Espresso crashing because of duplicate id used in application is there any solution working with duplicate id names.

```
onView(withId(R.id.linearMenu)).perform(click());
```

**Crash**

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: with id:
>   com.Example.activities:id/linearMenu

Comment: please post a complete stacktrace of the error. Duplicated ids are given the same value and should not cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

From here [count child elements with same id](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-testing-support-library/y6wqin2bWSY)

```
public static Matcher<View> withChildViewCount(final int count, final Matcher<View> childMatcher) {
return new BoundedMatcher<View, ViewGroup>(ViewGroup.class) {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int matchCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (childMatcher.matches(viewGroup.getChildAt(i))) {
                matchCount++;
            }
        }

        return matchCount == count;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("ViewGroup with child-count=" + count + " and");
        childMatcher.describeTo(description);
    }
};
```

}

Then just call

```
  onView(withId(R.id.view_group)).check(matches(withChildViewCount(2, withId(R.id.image_view))));
```

Comment: but it is an linear layout it cotains back icon

Comment: if i have 50 duplicate ids how to know  current id count